# Find position of string in DOM using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have the following problem:

I used the jQuery .text() function to acquire the pure text contents of an entire div element.

Now from within this string I have created a small substring.
I want to go back into the dom and find the strpos of this substring wrt the whole DOM.
here is the jsfiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/56GYt/

Here is the html

```
<body>
       <div class="geronimo"> this is the problem.<p> now what do i do</p>
       <p> this is the next problem<br> i hope someone can help
       <em> im cooked if i dont find a quick solution.</em>
       </div>
```

Now here is my jQuery.
          var textcontents = $(".geronimo").text();

```
     var textlengths = textcontents.length;
    //get a random number inside this length
    //create a searchstring from this
    var searchstring =
       textcontents.substring(Math.floor((Math.random()*textlengths)+1,textlengths));
      alert(searchstring);
     //now find this searchstring in the dom and return its strpos
```

I would like to emphasize that I would like a solution that possibly uses pure DOM methods, and not regexes to do this.
With regexes I know it's possible, but regexes are not recommended for this kind of work.

Comment: Seems like a generally bad idea, but what do I know -> `$('body').text().indexOf(searchstring);` ... [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/56GYt/1/) ???

Comment: Question is not clear to me??? i'm confused ^^